# Matlab: fread without knowing sizeA

Tags: matlab

If I have a binary file storing a list of integers, how can I read the file and store all the integers in an array, specifying the precision to be integer, but without specifying the number of integers in the file?

In the Matlab documentation for the fread function, the expected size of the array comes before the precision:

```
A = fread(fileID,sizeA,precision)
```

So what if you precision is known, but the size is unknown - and I want to load all of the integers in the file until the end of file is reached?

Answer (score 0):

If all the file contains is integers (let's say, `int32` values) stored in binary form, then the number of integers in the file is given by the following code snippet:

```
NAME_TYPE = 'int32';
SIZE_TYPE = 4;

fseek(fileID, 0, 'eof');
sizeA  = fix(ftell(fileID) / SIZE_TYPE);

fseek(fileID, 0, 'bof');
A = fread(fileID, sizeA, NAME_TYPE);
```

The code just calculates the number of integers as the size of the file (in bytes) divided by the number of bytes per integer value, then it reads that amount of integer values from the file.

Comment: also you can specify Inf in the size argument of the fread function and that should solve your problem: fread(fileID, Inf, 'int32')

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro Thanks for the comment, your solution is way better than mine. I think it would be good to post it as an answer, so it may be chosen as such.

Answer (score 0):

`fread(fileID,inf,precision)` reads an 'infinite' number of samples (i.e. to the end of the file).